# Skipping / Taking strategy with two merged lists

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

Any ideas how to proceed with this.

Background:

This is a bit of a weird domain, but essentially I have a table of Persons (which holds the master record) and a Listing table which holds historic versions of that person.
A listing always has a Person, a Person doesn't always have a Listing

How the Function Works:

I have 2 lists that are pulled from my db based on the inputs of 3 fields in combination (surname, firstname, idnumber) or an exact match on the id number

```
var efListingPersons = (from d in myentity.Listings.Include("Person")
    where ((
    (d.ListingSurname == (inputPerson.Surname ?? d.ListingSurname))
    && (d.ListingFirstName == (inputPerson.Firstname ?? d.ListingFirstName))
    && (d.ListingIdNumber == (inputPerson.IdNumber ?? d.ListingIdNumber))
)
||
(d.ListingIdNumber == (inputPerson.IdNumber)))
select d.Person).Distinct();


var efPersons = (from d in myentity.Persons
     where ((
    (d.Surname == (inputPerson.Surname ?? d.Surname))
    && (d.FirstName == (inputPerson.Firstname ?? d.FirstName))
    && (d.IdNumber == (inputPerson.IdNumber ?? d.IdNumber))
)
||
(d.IdNumber == (inputPerson.IdNumber)))
select d);
```

I then want to merge the two lists, and remove the duplicates (I have correctly donw the EqualityComparer, and this works nicely

```
return (efListingPersons.Union(efPersons).Select(o => new Person()
        {
            ID = o.Id,
            Firstname = o.FirstName,
            Surname = o.Surname
        }).ToList());
```

So this all works 100% and has for some time.
But now I am getting a lot of data in my tables and I would like to make this more efficient by introducing paging. This is also easy enough. I could just pass into the method values for the skip and the take, but I have this nagging feeling that if I do this on the two separate queries I will get warped results owing to the fact that the two tables will have records in different orders. Results look correct to me, but I just need a bit of a hand with the logic.

So in essence, my question is whether my data will be relyable if I do two seperate skip/takes on the two separate lists

Thanks

Comment: If you want the order to be consistent, you should `orderby` some unique value(s) at a correct location

Comment: How would you be doing your paging? Would you be paging by `Person`? If so, you should be fine by simply adding `Skip`/`Take` to your `Person` query.

Comment: paging by person indeed.

Comment: So then you should be able to page your `Person` results and modify your `PersonListing` query to only look for those records that have a match in your `efPersons` collection, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Does `Person` have a `Listings` property?

Comment: Yes. A person has a collection of Listings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom line is you are displaying paged `Person`s that match some criteria, either directly or indirectly. So it can be one query and its base shape can be

```
myentity.Persons.Where(...).OrderBy(p => p.SomeProperty).Skip(x).Take(y);
```

Now what to put in the `Where`?

The direct conditon:

```
Where(p => p.ListingSurname == (inputPerson.Surname ?? p.ListingSurname)
        && p.ListingFirstName == (inputPerson.Firstname ?? p.ListingFirstName)
        && p.ListingIdNumbe == (inputPerson.IdNumber ?? p.ListingIdNumber))
```

The indirect condition, if `Person` has a property `Listings`:

```
Where(p => p.Listings.Any(l =>
        l.ListingSurname == (inputPerson.Surname ?? l.ListingSurname)
        && l.ListingFirstName == (inputPerson.Firstname ?? l.ListingFirstName)
        && l.ListingIdNumbe == (inputPerson.IdNumber ?? l.ListingIdNumber)))
```

Or else

```
Where(p => myentity.Listings.Any(l =>
        l.Person == p
        && l.ListingSurname == (inputPerson.Surname ?? l.ListingSurname)
        && l.ListingFirstName == (inputPerson.Firstname ?? l.ListingFirstName)
        && l.ListingIdNumbe == (inputPerson.IdNumber ?? l.ListingIdNumber)))
```

(You can either chain the `Where`s or combine them with `&&`)